# C++ Program Hanging Indefinetely

Tags: c++

I have written code to solve a programming problem.

To summarise the problem, I have three balls - *red*, *green*, and *blue*. I am given a number *k*. I have to systematically destroy each ball i.e., destroy one red, then move onto green, destroy one green, then move onto blue, destroy one blue, and then start over from red again.

In case there are zero balls, I should just move onto the next ball.

In the end, I have to return the colour of the k-th ball that is destroyed.

The constraints for this problem are:

- r, g and b will each be between 1 and 1000000000000 (10^12), inclusive.
- k will be between 1 and r+g+b, inclusive.

To solve this problem, I have written the following code:

```
std::string getColor(long r, long g, long b, long k)
{
    long balls[] {r, g, b};

    int index = 0;

    long count = 0;

    std::string lastDestroyed = "";

    std::string colors[] {"RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"};

    while (count != k)
    {
        if (balls[index] > 0)
        {
            balls[index]--;
            lastDestroyed = colors[index];
            count++;
            index = (index + 1) % 3; 
        }
        else
            index = (index + 1) % 3; 
    }

    return lastDestroyed;
}
```

My program produces the correct output for all the test cases for which I tested so far, except one, for which it hangs indefinitely. This is for the case in which

- r = 1000000000000
- g = 1
- b = 1
- k = 1000000000002

The correct output for this test case is "RED" but my program just hangs indefinitely. I would like to know what I did wrong to cause this. Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

========== 
Here are a few more test cases and expected outputs in case my description of the problem isn't clear enough.

Input: r = 1, g = 1, b = 1, k = 3 
Expected output: "BLUE"

Input: r = 3, g = 4, b = 5, k = 4 
Expected output: "RED"

Input: r = 7, g = 7, b = 1, k = 7 
Expected output: "GREEN"

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program?  Maybe start by adding some debug messages to track your progress?

Comment: @StephenNewell I have tried debugging but I couldn't figure out what I had done wrong, which is why I posted my question to SO, in case anybody can spot any mistake and point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is `sizeof(long)` on your platform?

Comment: Well, counting down from `1000000000000` will take some time. Think about a non-iterative apporach. You are not supposed to write a simulation, but find a formula that describes only the result.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, 8 bytes. I have tried changing `long` to `unsigned long` but that still causes the program to hang.

Comment: @churill, you are right. But still, I would be interested in knowing what I did wrong that is causing the program to hang.

Comment: did you change both `count` and `k` to `unsigned long` or one of them only? doesn't matter though, since compiler would convert signed to unsigned on comparison. can you show the code where you call this function?

Comment: If `long` (or even `unsigned long`) on your system are 32-bit, then your code is being affected by overflow.   Both those values of `r` and `k` (`1000000000000` and `1000000000002` respectively) are outside the range that 32-bit `long` (or even `unsigned long`) can represent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is probably not hanging. Have a look at this, executed on my i9 system:

[image]

So if we extrapolate until we reach your input:

[image]

Your program will likely take (on my computer) around 10000s (2.8 hours) to run!

You are going to need to approach this issue differently, perhaps look into a mathematical or logical approach. For example, if you are destroying only reds in a row, won't you **always** destroy only reds?